# Gwt RPC in development mode

Tags: gwt-rpc

I am wondering if I can test my RPC in Developement mode.Does service will be invoked from the client if I run my GWT project in development mode ?

EDIT :
Is it possible to test GWT RPC mechanism in GWT development mode as we do in production/web mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can implement RPC in development mode.
Here is the link form Google's GWT tutorial :
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

The sample application in the tutorial successfully implements GWT RPC. You don't need to run the application in production mode just for implementing/testing RPC.
If you are confused due to the fact that without setting any server(externally), How come you be able to do client-server programming(RPC),then don't be. 
GWT has its own internal server called Jetty Server to take care of this situation.

Hope this helps.